# HDF5 rowmajor or colmajor

Tags: hdf5

Is it possible to know if a matrix stored in HDF5 format is in RowMajor or ColMajor? For example when I save matrices from octave, which stores them internally as ColMajor, I need to transpose them when I read them in my C code where matrices are stored in RowMajor, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Yossarian pointed out. HDF5 always stores data as row-major (C convention). Octave is the same as Fortran and internally stores data as column-major.

When writing a matrix from Octave, the HDF5 layer does the transpose for you, so it is always written as row-major no matter what language you use. This provides the portability of the file.

There is a very good example in the HDF5 User's Guide section 7.3.2.5, as mentioned by @Yossarian. Here's the example (almost) reproduced using Octave:

```
octave:1> A = [ 1:3; 4:6 ]
A =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6

octave:2> save("-hdf5", "test.h5", "A")
octave:3> quit

~$ h5dump test.h5
HDF5 "test.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   COMMENT "# Created by Octave 3.6.4, Fri Jun 13 08:36:16 2014 MDT <user@localhost>"
   GROUP "A" {
      ATTRIBUTE "OCTAVE_NEW_FORMAT" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STD_U8LE
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
         DATA {
         (0): 1
         }
      }
      DATASET "type" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE 7;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
         DATA {
         (0): "matrix"
         }
      }
      DATASET "value" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F64LE
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 3, 2 ) / ( 3, 2 ) }
         DATA {
         (0,0): 1, 4,
         (1,0): 2, 5,
         (2,0): 3, 6
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```

Notice how the HDF5 layer has transposed the matrix to make sure it is stored in row-major format.

Then an example of reading it in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <hdf5.h>

#define FILE "test.h5"
#define DS   "A/value"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int n = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int rank = 0;
        hid_t file_id;
        hid_t space_id;
        hid_t dset_id;
        herr_t stat;
        hsize_t *dims = NULL;
        int *data = NULL;

        file_id  = H5Fopen(FILE, H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT);
        dset_id  = H5Dopen(file_id, DS, dset_id);

        space_id = H5Dget_space(dset_id);
        n    = H5Sget_simple_extent_npoints(space_id);
        rank = H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims(space_id);

        dims = malloc(rank*sizeof(int));
        stat = H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(space_id, dims, NULL);

        printf("rank: %d\t dimensions: ", rank);
        for (i = 0; i < rank; ++i) {
                if (i == 0) {
                        printf("(");
                }
                printf("%llu", dims[i]);
                if (i == (rank -1)) {
                        printf(")\n");
                } else {
                        printf(" x ");
                }
        }
        data = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        memset(data, 0, n*sizeof(int));
        stat  = H5Dread(dset_id, H5T_NATIVE_INT, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT,
                         data);


        printf("%s:\n", DS);
        for (i = 0; i < dims[0]; ++i) {
                printf(" [ ");
                for (j = 0; j < dims[1]; ++j) {
                        x = i * dims[1] + j;
                        printf("%d ", data[x]);
                }
                printf("]\n");
        }

        stat  = H5Sclose(space_id);
        stat  = H5Dclose(dset_id);
        stat  = H5Fclose(file_id);


        return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When compiled and run gives:

```
~$ h5cc -o rmat rmat.c
~$ ./rmat
rank: 2  dimensions: (3 x 2)
A/value:
 [ 1 4 ]
 [ 2 5 ]
 [ 3 6 ]
```

This is great as it means the matrices are stored optimized in memory. What it does mean though is that you have to change how you do your calculations. For row-major you need to do pre-multiplication, while for column-major you should be doing post-multiplication.
Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784791/4x4-matrix-pre-multiplication-vs-post-multiplication), hopefully it is explained a bit clearer.

Does this help?

Comment: Thx for the very detailed example. But based on your example, HDF5 does not store the matrix in RowMajor: the matrix `A`, in Octave memory, in ColMajor, would appear as a 1D vector containing the values `{1,4,2,5,3,6}`. Also, dim[0]=2 and dim1[1]=3. When you read A in the C prog, the matrix read has mixed-up dimensions, and the RowMajor, 1D memory equivalent of the read A matrix is also {1,4,2,5,3,6}. I would expected `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`. At least, I would expect some hints in the HDF5 file to know if the memory layout for the matrix coeff when writing was row or col major to read it well.

Answer (score 8):

HDF5 stores data in row major order:

> HDF5 uses C storage conventions, assuming that the last listed dimension is the fastest-changing dimension and the first-listed dimension is the slowest changing.

from the [HDF5 User's Guide](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/12_Dataspaces.html).

**However**, if you're using Octave's built-in HDF5 interface, it will automatically transpose the arrays for you. In general, how the data is actually written in the HDF5 file should be completely opaque to the end-user, and the interface should deal with differences in array ordering, etc.

Comment: So when I read data exported from octave and they are transposed it is due to the fact that Octave did not follow HDF5 conventions, right?

Comment: I'm using a code in C++ written by myself. I just read the dataset dimensions then read the values.

Comment: I have the opposite problem: trying to read an HDF5 file created by something other than Octave, and reading in Octave, the matrix is transposed. According to [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=565216#20) "Octave's load function is only designed to load HDF5 files created by Octave.  There is no guarantee that it can load any and all arbitrary HDF5 files.  If it loads anything else, then it was just luck." I don't know if this is authoritative, but I consider this really bad: if my matrix had been square, it would not be obvious that it had been transposed.