# Read .mat file in Python. But the shape of the data changed

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, file-io, mat-file

```
 % save .mat file in the matlab    
train_set_x=1:50*1*51*61*23;   
train_set_x=reshape(train_set_x,[50,1,51,61,23]);   
save(['pythonTest.mat'],'train_set_x','-v7.3');
```

The data obtained in the matlab is in the size of (50,1,51,61,23).

I load the .mat file in Python with the instruction of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874461/read-mat-files-in-python).

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np, h5py
f = h5py.File('pythonTest.mat', 'r')
train_set_x = f.get('train_set_x')
train_set_x = np.array(train_set_x)
```

The output of train_set_x.shape is `(23L, 61L, 51L, 1L, 50L)`. It is expected to be `(50L, 1L, 51L, 61L, 23L)`. So I changed the shape by

```
train_set_x=np.transpose(train_set_x, (4,3,2,1,0))
```

I am curious about the change in data shape between Python and matlab. Is there some errors in my code?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24116713/1714410

Comment: For earlier `.mat` versions, `scipy.io.loadmat` produces arrays with the same  shape as MATLAB, but `order='F'`.  Thus it sort of hides this difference.

Comment: @hpaulj: What do you mean by early? What's the behaviour change for "late" mat versions?

Comment: MATLAB `save` takes a version option. `V7` and earlier use a native MATLAB file format, not `hdf5`.  `loadmat` handles those.  I can post a Octave/numpy example if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have any errors in the code. There is a fundamental difference between Matlab and python in the way they treat multi-dimensional arrays.
Both Matalb and python store all the elements of the multi-dim array as a single contiguous block in memory. The difference is the order of the elements:
**Matlab**, (like fortran) stores the elements in a column-first fashion, that is storing the elements according to the dimensions of the array, for 2D:

```
 [1 3;
  2 4]
```

In contrast, **Python**, stores the elements in a row-first fashion, that is starting from the *last* dimension of the array:

```
[1 2;
 3 4];
```

So a block in memory with *size* `[m,n,k]` in Matlab is seen by python as an array of *shape* `[k,n,m]`.

For more information see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

BTW, instead of transposing `train_set_x`, you might try setting its order to "Fortran" order (col-major as in Matlab):

```
 train_set_x = np.array(train_set_x, order='F')
```

Comment: Is the result different from transposing when you set `order='F'`? Or does it only make a difference in memory usage?

Comment: in `numpy` transposing is an O(1) operation: it does not re-locate elements in the memory, only hanges meta data of the array (its [`strides`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html)). I suppose you can compare the `strides` and `shape` between reading with `order="F"` and transposing. I guess these two methods amounts to the same object.

Comment: Thanks! It is good to know about the `order` argument, even if transposing yields the same result.

Comment: @mwormser I suppose it is more "correct" in this scenario to use the `order="F"` way, it makes it clear that the code expects the data to be in different order due to external program storage convention.

Comment: I tried the `order="F"` and transposing. But the output of `print(train_set_x.shape)` is different. It is `(50L, 1L, 51L, 61L, 23L)` for transposing, but `(23L, 61L, 51L, 1L, 50L)` for `order="F"`.