# How to get the memory layout of a HDF5 array with h5py?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

In numpy one can check whether an array is C-ordered or F-ordered with `my_array.flags`. What is the equivalent for a HDF5 dataset read with h5py?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HDF5 rowmajor or colmajor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116713/hdf5-rowmajor-or-colmajor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html):

> An HDF5 dataset created with the default settings will be contiguous; in other words, laid out on disk in traditional C order.

Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24116713/6522112) for more details. Long story short, your arrays are automatically converted if needed and everything is stored in C order.