# h5py performs many small reads when accessing data over a file-like object

Tags: hdf5, python-3.8, h5py

I have the following two issues with `h5py` when passing it a Python file-like object that streams data over a network connection (the file-like object is efficient, e.g. doesn't perform full file scans for ranged reads, using `smart_open`).

- `h5py` appears to make many calls to `read(...)` each time reading ~115k bytes (each read varies by a few hundred bytes).
- `h5py` appears to be operating in column major mode, even though [this article says it's row major](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116713/hdf5-rowmajor-or-colmajor), with a documentation reference.

I was able to count read calls by setting the `read` function on my file object to a local read function that counts calls and bytes, using `functools.partial` to do so.

My data is shaped as such:

```
print(h5file['table']) -> <HDF5 dataset "table": shape (1028, 7818600), type "<u2">
```

Test:

- A) When I read `h5file['table'][0, :1024]` there are `20` read calls (`6` of which are `~115k`), and `702,325` bytes are read in total.
- B) When I read `h5file['table'][0, :2048]` there are `25` read calls (`6` of which are `~115k`), and `702,325` bytes are read in total.
- C) When I read `h5file['table'][0, :2048]` there are `25` read calls (`11` of which are `~115k`, and `1,278,470` bytes are read in total.
- D) When I read `h5file['table'][:, :2048]` there are `25` read calls (`11` of which are `~115k`, and `1,278,470` bytes are read in total.
- E) When I read `h5file['table'][0, :1000000]` there are `64` read calls (`50` of which are `~115k`, and `5,772,539` bytes are read in total.

Conclusions:

- The data cannot be stored row major, otherwise `A` and `B` would be different (same for `C` and `D`).
- The data chunks size is `~115k` +/- a few hundred bytes which varies from call to call.
- The data must be compressed because total bytes of the final array is more than the bytes transferred.

Questions:

- Can I change the read chunk size so that there are fewer calls to read? Network latency limits me to about 2 reads per second which are run in series. This becomes very slow. Total bandwidth for large single-read operations is much faster.
- Can I confirm that the data is stored in column major format? This makes sense because this is sensor data which samples each of `1028` channels repeatedly. But since I read that hdf5 is always column major creates a discrepancy that I'd like to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compression and chunked I/O are features of HDF5/h5py. (Compression is automatically implemented when chunked I/O is used). Start by checking the dataset chunksize attribute: `print(h5file['table'].chunks)`. Likely this will confirm the 115k value you see. The chunk shape should also indicate why you see read order as column major instead of row major -- because chunk shape[1](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/h5repack) is larger than chunk shape[0].

If the chunk size is causing the problem, you should use larger chunk size. However, AFAIK, you have to create a new file with new datasets to change to do so.

For reference, here is an example showing a simple array written with 3 different chunk shapes defined. The file is closed then reopened in read mode. Data is read and written to a new file using a larger chunk size. This works around a h5py limitation with `group.copy()` (it uses the same chunk parameter when it copies datasets). You can also copy datasets and modify chunk I/O attributes with the 'h5repack' external utility from **The HDF Group**, ref: [h5repack doc page](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/h5repack).

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

size= 100
arr = np.random.random(size*size*size).reshape(size,size,size)

# Create file with small chunk size
with h5py.File('SO_69681364.h5_1','w') as h5file:
    h5file.create_dataset('chunked_a0',data=arr,chunks=(1,size,size))
    h5file.create_dataset('chunked_a1',data=arr,chunks=(size,1,size))
    h5file.create_dataset('chunked_a2',data=arr,chunks=(size,size,1))
    
    print(h5file['chunked_a0'].chunks)
    print(h5file['chunked_a1'].chunks)
    print(h5file['chunked_a2'].chunks)

# Open previous file and copy data to new file with larger chunk size
with h5py.File('SO_69681364_1.h5','r') as h5fr, \
      h5py.File('SO_69681364_2.h5','w') as h5fw:

    ds = h5fr['chunked_a0']
    h5fw.create_dataset('chunked_a0',data=ds,chunks=(10,size,size))
    h5fw.create_dataset('chunked_a1',data=ds,chunks=(size,10,size))
    h5fw.create_dataset('chunked_a2',data=ds,chunks=(size,size,10))
    
    print(h5fw['chunked_a0'].chunks)
    print(h5fw['chunked_a1'].chunks)
    print(h5fw['chunked_a2'].chunks)
```