# Matrix calculations for depth map in OpenGL are wrong

Tags: python, matrix, opengl, pyopengl

I am trying to achieve shadow mapping in my `pyopengl` project and something is wrong with the matrix calculations. The view of the 'sun' is always from coordinates x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 and the render distance is `1` correlating with black and white values from 0 to 1.

If I remove the multiplication of the `mvp_matrix` and `model_matrix` and only pass the `model_matrix` to the shader the same output is being produced, so something is up with that

Here are how my matrices are created:

```py
    def update_light_view_matrix(self, direction: vec3, center: vec3) -> None:
        """
        Updates the "view" matrix of the light. This creates a view matrix which
        will line up the direction of the "view cuboid" with the direction of the
        light. The light itself has no position, so the "view" matrix is centered
        at the center of the "view cuboid". The created view matrix determines
        where and how the "view cuboid" is positioned in the world. The size of
        the view cuboid, however, is determined by the projection matrix.
        :param direction: the light direction, and therefore the direction that the "view cuboid" should be pointing.
        :param center: the center of the "view cuboid" in world space.
        :return:
        """
        direction = direction.normalize()
        self.__light_view_matrix = mat4().identity()
        pitch = math.acos(math.sqrt(direction.x**2 + direction.z**2))
        self.__light_view_matrix = self.__light_view_matrix.rotate(pitch, vec3(1, 0, 0))
        yaw = math.degrees(math.atan(direction.x / direction.z))
        yaw = yaw - 180 if direction.z > 0 else yaw
        self.__light_view_matrix = self.__light_view_matrix.rotate(-math.radians(yaw), vec3(0, 1, 0))
        self.__light_view_matrix = self.__light_view_matrix.translate(-center)

    def update_ortho_projection_matrix(self, width: float, height: float, length: float) -> None:
        """
        Creates the orthographic projection matrix. This projection matrix
        basically sets the width, length and height of the "view cuboid", based
        on the values that were calculated in the ShadowBox class.
        :param width: shadow box width.
        :param height: shadow box height.
        :param length: shadow box length.
        :return:
        """
        self.__projection_matrix = mat4()
        self.__projection_matrix[(0, 0)] = 2.0 / width
        self.__projection_matrix[(1, 1)] = 2.0 / height
        self.__projection_matrix[(2, 2)] = -2.0 / length
        self.__projection_matrix[(3, 3)] = 1
```

The model matrix is definetly correct.

```py
...
self.__projection_view_matrix = self.__projection_matrix * self.__light_view_matrix
...
mvp_matrix = self.__projection_view_matrix * model_matrix
```

I think I'll add the outputs of the matrix calculations so you can verify them:

```py
projection_matrix:
[   0.0036,    0.0000,    0.0000,    0.0000]
[   0.0000,    0.0069,    0.0000,    0.0000]
[   0.0000,    0.0000,   -0.0128,    0.0000]
[   0.0000,    0.0000,    0.0000,    1.0000]

light_view_matrix:
[  -0.7071,    0.0000,   -0.7071,  -15.1670]
[  -0.5145,    0.6860,    0.5145,   22.6592]
[   0.4851,    0.7276,   -0.4851,    1.9242]
[   0.0000,    0.0000,    0.0000,    1.0000]

projection_view_matrix:
[  -0.0026,    0.0000,   -0.0026,   -0.0552]
[  -0.0035,    0.0047,    0.0035,    0.1560]
[  -0.0062,   -0.0093,    0.0062,   -0.0245]
[   0.0000,    0.0000,    0.0000,    1.0000]

mvp_matrix:
[   1.0000,    0.0000,    0.0000,  601.0000]
[   0.0000,    1.0000,    0.0000,   -1.5510]
[   0.0000,    0.0000,    1.0000,  778.0000]
[   0.0000,    0.0000,    0.0000,    1.0000]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784791/4x4-matrix-pre-multiplication-vs-post-multiplication

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 'mistake' lies in calculating the Model-View-Projection matrix in your code instead of calculating it in the vertex shader.

The `pycgtypes` library states that it's compatible with OpenGL although this isn't true and calculates the matrices wrong.

Loading the three separate matrices into your vertex shader and calculating the `mvp_matrix` there solves the issue.

```
#version 150

in vec3 in_position;

uniform mat4 light_view_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;

void main(void){

    mat4 mvp_matrix = projection_matrix * light_view_matrix * model_matrix;

    gl_Position = mvp_matrix * vec4(in_position, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: *"The 'mistake' lies in calculating the Model-View-Projection matrix in your code instead of calculating it in the vertex shader."* - No. Of course it is possible to multiply the matrices on the CPU and to pass one MVP matrix to the shader. In your program only the matrix multiplication seems to be broken. This, however, nobody could spot, because this part of the code is missing in the question.

Comment: @Rabbid76 didn't expect this because I used the `pycgtypes` module to calculate the vertices and matrices. I didn't have issues with it beforehand and didn't expect it to calculate the matrices wrong. Would you first assume that a module you imported is doing something before you think you did something wrong?

Comment: I am very sure that the model does nothing wrong. You have certainly used it incorrectly. You probably need to multiply the matrices from the other direction or transpose them. In your question you did not even mention that you are using this module.